# Months on chart

Tags: sql

[image]

```
    Select      substring(convert(nvarchar, A.CreatedAt, 107), 0, 4) as 'Month',
                COUNT(*) as 'Booked',
                sum(cast(A.IsCancelled as int)) as 'Cancelled' 
    From        ReservationTbl A
    group by    substring(convert(nvarchar, A.CreatedAt, 107), 0, 4)
```

How can I get data from previous months on current year for my chart?
And if there is no data on a month how to declare and post zero on data?

Comment: provider your expected output and sample data

Comment: Did you try adding a having-clause like having year(A.CreatedAt)=2018

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That query is product specific.)

Comment: mssql . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

Like Allan Bertelsen said; use a where clause for year and month with getdate()

```
Select      substring(convert(nvarchar, A.CreatedAt, 107), 0, 4) as 'Month',
            COUNT(*) as 'Booked',
            sum(cast(A.IsCancelled as int)) as 'Cancelled'

From        ReservationTbl A

where       YEAR(A.CreatedAt) = YEAR(getdate())
            and MONTH(A.CreatedAt) <= MONTH(getdate())

group by    substring(convert(nvarchar, A.CreatedAt, 107), 0, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify previous month and current month in where clause

```
Select substring(convert(nvarchar, A.CreatedAt, 107), 0, 4) as 'Month',
      COUNT(*) as 'Booked',
      sum(cast(A.IsCancelled as int)) as 'Cancelled' 
From ReservationTbl A
where YEAR(A.CreatedAt) = YEAR(getdate())
      and MONTH(A.CreatedAt)>= month(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) and MONTH(A.CreatedAt) <= MONTH(getdate())
group by substring(convert(nvarchar, A.CreatedAt, 107), 0, 4)
```